# Spring - Unable to obtain valid Security Context through HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository when running app in multiple instances

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have persistent remember-me security working except I am unable to retrieve user roles.  On my local machine running 1 instance, the user roles are populated.

It looks like it is because of Http Session mismanagement:

```
2014-04-29T12:12:58-04:00 - bcm-gis - 1 - app - 10.179.73.100 - stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-04-29T12:12:58-04:00 - bcm-gis - 1 - app - 10.179.73.100 - stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
2014-04-29T12:12:58-04:00 - bcm-gis - 1 - app - 10.179.73.100 - stdout.log: DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
```

The users stay logged in across instances, so it leads me to believe that there is some session info available to the filter chain.  Also, persistent login data is being saved in the database.

I have very little remember-me config:

```
<http>
...
   <remember-me user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
        data-source-ref="dataSource" />
</http>
```

Then I have some session config:

```
<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <beans:property name="key" value="spring" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myAuthFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"
            ref="sas" />
    <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />
```

The authentication manager uses an LdapAuthenticationProvider that is working appropriately.

Has anyone seen this issue before?  Do you want to see some more config?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple instances" ? Also by "the users stay logged in across instances" ? If there is not security context or session, how can they be logged in?

Comment: The application runs on Stackato so a user may be redirected to 1 of 3 instances on each http request.  I believe the user is authenticated further down the filter chain by AnonymousAuthenticationFilter which may or may not actually query LDAP.

Comment: I don't know anything about stackato, but id you mean that there are three separate server processes, with no session clustering, then they won't share the authentication state between them, since it it stored in the session by default. The log message says there is no session in the current process, so the user can't be authenticated. `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` doesn't authenticate the user. It's just an infrastructure component to represent an unauthenticated user.